# How to Connect MySql from Eclipse using Data Source Explorer

Tags: mysql, eclipse, eclipse-dtp

I need help. Could you please answer these question? I would like to connect eclipse to my database  and I have tried these in eclipse: `Window>Show View>Other>Data Source Explorer`. After that we get `Database Connections` under the eclipse  and then right click on the database connection and click on `New...` then select `MySql` under `Connection Profile Types:` and I click on `New Driver Definition`. Under `New Driver Definition` dialog, there exists `MySql JDBC Driver` with specific System Version. I choose one, but the `OK` button is disabled. Also at the top it says: "*Unable to locate JAR/zip in file system as specified by the driver definition: mysql-connector-java-xxx-bin.jar*".

---

How can I specify a Driver Template and Definition Name under `New Driver Definition` dialog of Data Source Explorer (in Data Tools Platform)

Comment: will you please anyone know the answer could please post it

Comment: Mr.Fredrick Gauss i have install the MYSQL 5.1 but it showing the same error ...... is there any other method to slove these problem ? Will Know the another method could please post it

Answer (score 9):

I dont know your Eclipse version or your MySql server version but for `Kepler` and `mysql 5.5 server`, here what I did. First I downloaded mysql connector java jar file(*mysql-connector-java-5.1.36-bin.jar*) from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads. Then On the `New Driver Definition` dialog page, I choose `MySQL JDBC Driver|MySQL|5.1` under `Name/Type` tag. Go to `JAR List` tab `Clear all` and `Add JAR/Zip...` and choosed my already downloaded jar file. Finally at the `Properties` tab I filled them like this:

- **Connection URL**:    `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306`
- **Database Name**:     `MyDatabaseNameHere`
- **Driver Class**:      `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`
- **Password**:          `MyPasswordHere`
- **User ID**:           `root`

In the end, `OK` butten changed to enabled and that is all.

Comment: my eclipse version is  mars latest version ,  my Sql version is 5.6

Comment: please consider my error here Error : java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: while iam doing what i mentioned the procedure i get these error Unable to locate JAR/zip in file system as specified by the driver definition: mysql-connector-java-5.1.0-bin.jar.

Comment: what is your operation system? did you downloaded .jar file from mysql site?

Comment: ya i have downloaded the file .

Comment: you should have connected to your mysql instance from command prompt/terminal before setting the connection properties just to make sure connection string is ok

Comment: Just now i  checked in command prompt ....... Connection is ok . and i have downloaded operating system windows7 x64bit

Comment: last status:Just now i checked in command prompt ....... Connection is ok . and i have downloaded operating system windows7 x64bit –

Comment: error:Unable to locate JAR/zip in file system as specified by the driver definition: mysql-connector-java-5.1.0-bin.jar

Comment: Thank you   Fredrick Gauss for supporting to my project

Comment: I see you didnt do what i suggested. You need to download mysql-connector-java-5.1.0-bin.jar file from internet. In the JAR tab you need to edit its path.

Comment: I am getting connection success but SSL file is not there ...   could any one no  the problem ?please tell me.....

Comment: Your problem and your definitions are not clear so I think no one would try to solve your problem. I think you have to get online-interactive support.Maybe [chat] . Or you can prepare a video demonstrating what are you doing during these steps.

Comment: still got the same error; com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client

Answer (score 4):

I also faced same issue. Just download the specific mysql JAR file needed. Now you need to add it to the JAR files tab. But before doing it click on clear all. That is the important step.